# Matlab Butterworth filter returing NaN

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to apply a butterworth filter in Matlab. I have set up the filter as follows:

```
[z,p,k] = butter(5,[30/2000,1000/2000]);
```

i.e. cut off below 30 Hz and above 1000 Hz (sampling at 2000 Hz)

The input data is a column in a larger matrix, A.

I am then applying the filter as follows:

```
M=filter(z,p,A(:,2));
```

and have also tried:

```
M=filtfilt(z,p,A(:,2));
```

A has 1577563 rows. The filter returns real values up to around row ~1700 but after that the entries are NaN. I have tried extracting a selection of the values from `A(:,2)` which generate NaN in M, however on their own, these return numbers, so I am assuming it is something to do with the length of A, rather than the specific values. It would seem this is an instability in the filter function, since the start of NaN differs on different tests.

I have tried reducing the order, but get similar results with 2nd and even 1st order filters.

If there is a way I would happily upload the data in `A(:,2)` however I am not sure how to do this in StackExchange.

Comment: I would guess that `NaN` occurs from a `0/0` operation somewhere. I have never seen this before, but may I ask if your signal is stationary? Or what magnitude does the signal have (approximately)?

Comment: I am applying this to several different data sets and getting the same problem for each. The average signal intensity is 0.1 - 1. I notice that by increasing the order of the filter to n, the point at which NaN starts increases to ~9900.

Comment: Ok, but the signal does not only take values between 0-1, right? So to say, does it have an average close to 0?

Comment: The means of the 4 signals I'm trying to apply this to are 0.0778, 0.0251, 0.0419 and 0.2532. The maximum values in each case are 0.9202, 1.2755, 2.2430 and 2.4905. The minimum values are all of the order 10^-4 or 10^-5.

Comment: Well it may be as you think, but obviously there are more code somewhere, so it is hard to say for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a perfect void idea of what you are trying to do. But well, there are *HUGE* issues on the code and in the concept:

1. The butter frequencies must be half the sampling frequency. Thus you
   are implementing 15Hz and 500Hz sampling at 2000Hz, which im sure are not what you need,
2. You are feeding the `filter` command with `ZPK` -zero, pole, filter-
   structure, and the 'filter' command receives `B` and `A` `TF`
   polynomials. This can lead to *unpredictable* wrong results,
3. You cannot set a *bandpass* between `f0` and `f1` when `f1` is the
   nyquist, half sampling rate, `fs/2`. If so, just use `f0` and set
   the filter as highpass!. if you still need a bandpass, choose
   `f1=900` or something close, not the *very* nyquist cut.

Here is a corrected version, for a sampled filter between 30Hz and 950Hz, sampling at 2000Hz:

```
   x  = randn(500,1);     % Input to the filter
   [b,a] = butter(5,[30/2000,950/2000]*2); 
   y=filter(b,a,x);
   fvtool(b,a);
   plot([x y]);
```

Greetings!...